# Conditionally update rows and then group

Tags: r, dplyr

Let me start by providing my sample dataset:

```
ID Start        Code End          Days
1  2016-03-01   A    2016-03-14   14
1  2016-03-01   A    2016-03-14   14
1  2016-03-01   B    2016-04-01   30
2  2016-02-01   A    2016-03-01   28
```

I'd like to, for each ID, and within this group, for each Code, check if the End is larger dan Start in the next row (if df$End[i] > df$Start[i+1]) and if so, update Start of the next row to End en recompute End (which is Start + Days) for that row i+1. The results should thus be:

```
ID Start        Code End          Days
1  2016-03-01   A    2016-03-14   14
1  2016-03-14   A    2016-03-28   14
1  2016-03-01   B    2016-04-01   30
2  2016-02-01   A    2016-03-01   28
```

Afterwards, if for a ID, and a Code the difference between df$End[i] - df$Start[i+1] <= 7, I would like to combine the rows, using the smallest df$Start and the largest df$End for this subset. Making:

```
ID Start        Code End          Days
1  2016-03-01   A    2016-03-28   14
1  2016-03-01   B    2016-04-01   30
2  2016-02-01   A    2016-03-01   28
```

Since my dataset is over 100M rows, I'd like a fast solution. Unfortunately I am pretty new to dplyr, so help is highly appreciated!

update: larger example:

```
ID  Start       Code  End         Days
1   2012-04-01  A     2012-04-07  7
1   2016-03-01  B     2016-03-15  15
1   2016-03-01  B     2016-05-29  90
1   2016-06-01  B     2016-08-29  90
1   2016-09-01  B     2016-11-29  90
1   2016-12-01  B     2017-02-28  90
1   2017-03-01  B     2017-05-09  90
1   2017-08-01  B     2017-10-29  90
1   2017-12-01  B     2018-02-28  90
2   2016-04-01  B     2016-04-14  14
```

This results in:

```
ID   Start       Code   End   
1    2012-04-01  A      2012-04-07
1    2016-03-01  B      2017-02-28
1    2017-03-01  B      2017-05-29
1    2018-08-01  B      2017-12-05
2    2016-04-01  B      2016-04-14
```

Where I would expect row 2 and  to be combined.

For the first step I tried:

```
 grouped_df <-
 df %>%
 group_by(ID, Code) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(Start, End), funs(as.Date)) %>%
 mutate(new_start = as.Date(ifelse(lag(End > Start), lag(End), Start), origin="1970-01-01")) %>%
```

mutate(new_stop= new_disp + Days)

However, if a new_end has been computed, we should now compare new_end and not End with new_start (and not Start).

Comment: How come that in the second row you expect `2016-12-15` and not `2016-11-29`?

Comment: Problem is that start is updated cummulatively. So if I have multiple entries for ID 1 and Code A, after changing the start of the second row, the end of the second row changes, and then, the start of the fourth one should change etc. So from 03-01 to 03-15 (row 2, 15 days), from 03-15 to 06-15 (row 3, 90 days), from 06-15 to 09-15 (row 4, 90 days) and from 09-15 to 12-15 (row 5, again 90 days).

Comment: Maybe a solution might be dat if the first Start + (for all rows with same ID en Code: sum(days)) < End: group them with Start as in first row and End computed as Start + sum(days))?

Comment: What if then there is a second Start + 1 < End; should it start again or?

Comment: It should always progress on the previous row. So if lag(Stop) > Start: update Start, recompute Stop. And repeat this process for all equal IDs and Codes.

Comment: You can try my edit, though I feel your data frame may be even more complex, unfortunately don't have time to simulate new observations. You will also see that I got `2016-12-10` and not `11` as this is the result of `as.Date("2016-03-15") + 270`.